# CURLINFO_FILETIME ignores images created via PHP

Tags: php, curl

Using CURL verifies the individual URL addresses where the images of their recent time change. For pictures, it works up until I hit the [URL generated via PHP script](http://www.medard-online.cz/scripts/getimage.php?initDate=140526_00&domain=2&variable=cloud&offset=3)

**How can I control I created these images through PHP script?**

```
$image_url = "http://www.medard-online.cz/scripts/getimage.php?initDate=140526_00&domain=2&variable=cloud&offset=3";

$curl = curl_init($image_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);

 if ($result === false) {
    die (curl_error($curl)); 
 }

$timestamp = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_FILETIME);
```

Answer (score 0):

CURLOPT_FILETIME *“attempt[s] to retrieve the modification date of the remote document”* (quote: PHP manual).

For that to work, the “remote document” must *deliver* that info in the first place, via a `LAST-MODIFIED` header. Normally this is done by the web server itself for static files – but when you are outputting data via your own script, you have to do that yourself as well. (Assuming the script delivering the image is indeed your own – if not, you can only ask the party providing access to the image to implement this for you.)